# Text/Card rotation in JS,CSS

Tags: javascript, css

[This is a visual of what I mean where half of the text dips behind the "card"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fajnR.png)    So our flip cards are almost working with no kinks however when we flip to the BACK of the card there is a slight delay for the text to show up in full. As you can see, the text sort of dips behind the card blocking half of it directly down the middle.  Also, this mistake seems to only happen the first time you flip the card. If you sit there and flip the card repeatedly front/back it fixes itself after the first flip. We have played around with the transition time, the Y angle degree etc but can't quite seem to get a perfect flip. Any help would be appreciated and this is my first time asking on here so if I haven't done something correctly I apologize. Below is just some of the code associated. If more is needed please let me know also I tried to post a screenshot of the issue but it would not finish loading.
***Some of the css***

```
.single-card__card-front {
  grid-area: middle;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.single-card__card-back {
  grid-area: middle;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transition-delay: 2s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.flip-show {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.94, 0, 1.15);
  opacity: 1;
}

.flip-hide {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.24, 0.94, 0, 1.15);
  opacity: 0;
}
```

***Some of the JS***

```
const getVisibleCards = () => {
    let currentCard = allCards[i];
    currentCard.classList.add('current-card');

    if (currentCard.classList.contains('next-card')) {
        currentCard.classList.remove('next-card');
    }
    if(currentCard.classList.contains('previous-card')){
        currentCard.classList.remove('previous-card')
    }
    //if there is a next card
    if (i < allCards.length - 1) {
        allCards[i + 1].classList = "single-card next-card"
    }
    //if there is a previous card
    if (i > 0) {
        allCards[i - 1].classList = "single-card previous-card"
    }
    if(i >= 2){ 
    allCards[i - 2].classList = 'single-card hidden-card'
    }
    if(i + 2 <= allCards.length){
        for(let nextHidden = i + 2; nextHidden <= allCards.length; nextHidden++)
        allCards[nextHidden].classList = 'single-card hidden-card'
    }
```

***Some more JS

```
const flipCard = () => {
    //switch them
    currentCard = allCards[i];
    cardFront = currentCard.querySelector('.single-card__card-front');
    cardBack = currentCard.querySelector('.single-card__card-back');
    //ternary
    currentCard.classList.toggle("flip-show");
    cardFront.classList.toggle("flip-hide");
    cardBack.classList.toggle("flip-show");
};
```

Comment: could you share a basic working example on https://codesandbox.io/ or jsbin or similar?

Comment: can you post some of the Javascript?

Comment: @JasonBK  let me know if thats enough JS i skipped the nextCard, previousCard stuff

Comment: @q3e   let me know if that picture helps you. i can look at getting a basic example a little later on today maybe